Connecting mealpy Python to excel
My problem is when I run the code and save it in excel workbook, all the formula disappears and only the data exist and saved in the workbook. I try to eliminate the data_only= True, but if I do so, the code cannot be run. So, how can I run the code without affecting the formula?
import openpyxl
from mealpy import FloatVar, SHADE

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book2.xlsx',data_only= True)
sheet = wb['Optimization']

def objective_function(solution):
    sheet['F4'].value = solution[0]
    sheet['F5'].value = solution[1]
    sheet['F6'].value = solution[2]
    sheet['F7'].value = solution[3]
    sheet['F8'].value = solution[4]
    sheet['F9'].value = solution[5]
    sheet['E16'].value = solution[6]
    sheet['F16'].value = solution[7]
    sheet['G16'].value = solution[8]
    sheet['H16'].value = solution[9]
    sheet['I16'].value = solution[10]
    sheet['J16'].value = solution[11]
    sheet['K16'].value = solution[12]
    sheet['L16'].value = solution[13]
    sheet['M16'].value = solution[14]
    sheet['N16'].value = solution[15]
    sheet['O16'].value = solution[16]
    sheet['P16'].value = solution[17]
    sheet['Q16'].value = solution[18]
    sheet['R16'].value = solution[19]
    sheet['S16'].value = solution[20]

    return sheet['U9'].value

problem = {
    "obj_func": objective_function,
    "bounds": FloatVar(ub=(1.,)*21, lb=(0.,)*21),
    "minmax": "min",
    "log_to": "console",
}

## Run the algorithm
optimizer = SHADE.OriginalSHADE(epoch=100, pop_size=50)
g_best = optimizer.solve(problem)
print(f"Best solution: {g_best.solution}, Best fitness: {g_best.target.fitness}")

wb.save('Book2.xlsx')

So, how can I run the code without affecting the formula?
Because I need to remain the original formula in the excel so that I can get the calculated final result after I have run the mealpy coding in Python.

Please edit your question and add your code and attempts.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I'm developer of mealpy.
I recommend you use different package for handling excel file. Here is my solution for your question.
import xlwings as xw
from mealpy import FloatVar, SHADE

# Open the Excel file
wb = xw.Book('Book2.xlsx')
sheet = wb.sheets['Sheet1']  # Change the sheet name if needed

def objective_function(solution):
    sheet.range('F4').value = solution[0]
    sheet.range('F5').value = solution[1]
    sheet.range('F6').value = solution[2]
    sheet.range('F7').value = solution[3]
    sheet.range('F8').value = solution[4]
    sheet.range('F9').value = solution[5]
    sheet.range('E16').value = solution[6]
    sheet.range('F16').value = solution[7]
    sheet.range('G16').value = solution[8]
    sheet.range('H16').value = solution[9]
    sheet.range('I16').value = solution[10]
    sheet.range('J16').value = solution[11]
    sheet.range('K16').value = solution[12]
    sheet.range('L16').value = solution[13]
    sheet.range('M16').value = solution[14]
    sheet.range('N16').value = solution[15]
    sheet.range('O16').value = solution[16]
    sheet.range('P16').value = solution[17]
    sheet.range('Q16').value = solution[18]
    sheet.range('R16').value = solution[19]
    sheet.range('S16').value = solution[20]

    return sheet.range('U9').value


problem = {
    "obj_func": objective_function,
    "bounds": FloatVar(ub=(1.,)*21, lb=(0.,)*21),
    "minmax": "min",
    "log_to": "console",
}

## Run the algorithm
optimizer = SHADE.OriginalSHADE(epoch=100, pop_size=50)
g_best = optimizer.solve(problem)
print(f"Best solution: {g_best.solution}, Best fitness: {g_best.target.fitness}")

# Close the Excel file when done (optional)
wb.close()

